# How to run Cucumnber-JVM tests in parallel using Gradle (Is there MVN FailSafe plugin equivalent in Gradle)

Tags: gradle, parallel-processing, cucumber-jvm, maven-surefire-plugin, maven-failsafe-plugin

I am trying to run Cucumber-JVM tests in parallel.
Instead of Maven we're using Gradle as build tool.

How to achieve CucumberJVM's parallel execution in this case, something similar to Maven's Failsafe Plugin?
Is it possible to achieve parallel run similar to Maven-SureFire plugin using Gradle?
Kindly give link to any resource or example. Thanks a lot

[image]

**Snapshot of Build.gradle**:
[image]

Comment: You can't. Use the Cucumber CLI or the JUnit Platform Console with the cucumber-junit-platform-engine. You have to use these from a grade task.

Comment: @M.P. Korstanje Is there sample example for it? Thanks

Comment: There should be some here: https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/master/junit-platform-engine